# Block the html in append

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding an element to div with following line:

```
$('#myDiv').append("<a href='www.google.com'>Google</a>");
```

But it is adding as html to `myDiv` how to add this code as a text ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#myDiv').text($('#myDiv').text() + "<a href='www.google.com'>Google</a>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use text. This shows you how to append "text"

```js
var my_div = $('#myDiv');
var my_string = "<a href='www.google.com'>Google</a>";

my_div.text(my_div.text() + my_string);

my_div.text(my_div.text() + "My additional string");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: I need to use append because i will add more items to this div.

Comment: @Okan give that a shot